# Nav bar not showing pages in my wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a problem with my WordPress theme (html5) nav bar not showing site pages properly.
See this at ChessatmyboarD chess blog at [ChessatmyboarD](http://chessat.richard-dickinson.com)

I have tried to fix this over the last few days but so far with no luck. I looked at the TwentyTen default WordPress3 theme but I cannot adapt the code to my theme.

Another small issue is that in IE my footer stays at the bottom of the page, but in FireFox there is a gap at the page bottom.

So I would greatly appreciate help to fix this nav bar WPtheme problem and any other advice to improve my new theme.

I look forward to helpful replies, many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK
No replies! Noone any interest in helping? Mmmmm?!....where are the wp theme developers on stackoverflow?
So  this is my reply (maybe just to myself!?).
I have managed to use Twenty Ten WPtheme code & style to get my WPTheme nav bar more as I need it/it needs to be!
I will continue to try & improve this my new theme.
I am now looking into how to add a home page nav bar link & I think & hope Twenty Ten theme may have an answer(?).
I still have to check how the footer displays in Firefox vs IE...
Best wishes to all WP theme creators-isn't WP3 & html5 and CSS£ a great new challenge!